# I'm having an issue in the console browser whenever I import the bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm a new to web development. I'm having an issue in the console browser whenever I import the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` saying:

> Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and
> navigator.platform
>
> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent,
> navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. In a future version of
> Chrome, the amount of information available in the User Agent string
> will be reduced. To fix this issue, replace the usage of
> navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with
> feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to
> navigator.userAgentData. Note that for performance reasons, only the
> first access to one of the properties is shown.
>
> AFFECTED RESOURCES 1 source bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1

I read the problem, how to fix it and also google it, but I'm really having a hard time understanding it and how to solve it...

might have someone here to help me... thank you in advance

[image: issue screenshot]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Since the detailed message mentioned Chrome, I tried Firefox and did not see the warning.  Just for reference - the message is only a warning and only appears when doing an inspect.  I would still feel better having a full explanation of what the issue is and if it is okay to ignore it.

Comment: Here is additional information about the source of the warning https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html

Comment: I have the same error, but this only happens if I open devtools. When I close devtools website works fine

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about somebody else's problem — if a library you use triggers deprecation errors then monitor the situation, raise a bug report with the vendor, and consider using a different library.

Comment: use this instead: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

This is a warning by Chrome that they'll be [restricting use of the `userAgent` string](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html) in the future. It basically means that the script you're loading may not work properly at some point, and you (the Bootstrap team) should work toward replacing use of those properties with other techniques.

There's nothing you need to do about it for now. Ideally the Bootstrap team will deal with it in a future release, or they'll pressure the Chromium team to delay such restrictions.

That said, [Bootstrap 4 end-of-life](https://github.com/twbs/release) is slated for November of 2022. You might consider migrating to Bootstrap 5 during that time to avoid complications down the road. The migration isn't too painful, mostly involving find-and-replace of class and attribute names plus a few other markup fixes for most apps.

Comment: Bootstrap v5.3.1 still has this problem.